# Thread pool not released

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I upgrade the firebase-admin to 9.2.0, and I want use `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendEachForMulticastAsync(multicastMessage)` to instead of the `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendMulticast(multicastMessage)`, but when `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendEachForMulticastAsync(multicastMessage)` is called, it appears to create a new thread pool every time. This seems to cause an issue of excessive local thread pool creation when the method is invoked frequently, consuming significant system resources and potentially leading to performance degradation, memory errors, and related issues

To address thread overflow, I rewrote `ThreadManager`, and set the pookSize to 10, can not get the callback

```
FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath))))
                        .setThreadManager(new CustomThreadManager(poolSize))
                        .build()
                FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
```

Comment: Get an instance only once, and reuse it for all calls to send...()

Comment: This doesn't work, it still prompts me that I can't create more threads

Comment: what prompt? you told it to pool 10 threads, did it create 10 threads? or did it try to create more threads than 10? or did it say it cannot create 10 threads? Please edit your question with the error message / stack trace

Comment: When I don't set poolSize, the sendEachForMulticastAsync method will create threads without restrictions, causing an OOM exception. When I rewrite ThreadManager and try to customize poolSize, I cannot receive a callback